# Python folium - add labels to drawn elements

Tags: leaflet, labeling, folium

Following the query here:

[Exporting GeoJSON with defined properties using Folium Draw plugin](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/445450/exporting-geojson-with-defined-properties-using-folium-draw-plugin)

I would like to add labels to the elements, which will be drawn and their features will be defined.

By following this article:

https://www.mkrgeo-blog.com/qgis2-web-fixing-labelling-issues-in-openlayers-map/

where the code comes from OpenLayers and we were able to define not only the label but also the font, etc I was going to prepare something for my particular case.

```
 {map}.on("draw:created", function(e){    
    var layer = e.layer;
        feature = layer.feature = layer.feature || {};
    let x = 1 
    var title = prompt("Please provide the name", "default");
    var value = prompt("Please provide the value", "undefined");
    var id = x++;
    var label = "";
    feature.type = feature.type || "Feature";
    var props = feature.properties = feature.properties || {};
    props.Id = id;
    props.Title = title;
    props.Value = value;       
    if (feature.get(title) !== null) {
    label = String(feature.get(title));
    }
    drawnItems.addLayer(layer);
```

In this case, I get an error:

**Uncaught TypeError: feature.get is not a function**

Next, I tried this thread

[get() and getProperties() are not a function, from a VectorLayer (GeoJSON)](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/313488/get-and-getproperties-are-not-a-function-from-a-vectorlayer-geojson)

and tweaked my code accordingly:

```
  {map}.on("draw:created", function(e){    
    var layer = e.layer;
        feature = layer.feature = layer.feature || {};
    let x = 1 
    var title = prompt("Please provide the name", "default");
    var value = prompt("Please provide the value", "undefined");
    var id = x++;
    var label = "";
    feature.type = feature.type || "Feature";
    var props = feature.properties = feature.properties || {};
    props.Id = id;
    props.Title = title;
    props.Value = value;
var newsource = e.target;
if (newsource.getState() === 'ready') {
  var myFeatures = newsource.getFeatures(); 
 
  var display = myFeatures.get(title);
}
    if (display !== null) {
    label = String(display);
    }
    drawnItems.addLayer(layer);
```

but now I am getting an error:

**Uncaught TypeError: newsource.getState is not a function**

which led me to the next thread:

[OpenLayers GeoJSON t.getState is not a function](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/288644/openlayers-geojson-t-getstate-is-not-a-function)

after which I realized, that importing OpenLayers library is necessary.

Is there any option for displaying the labels next to drawn shapes in Python folium?